# show above input.focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm trying `input.focus();`  on form input with error. The cursor points on that input but Since I have a fixed header whose height is around 100px,the input field is not visible.

Is there a way where I can go beyond that input fields something like `input.focus(-100);`?

I have also tried `input.scrollTop();` but it doesn't go any where near that input.

Comment: have you tried [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)?

Comment: can't you use window.scrollTop() to scroll the document rather than the input?

Comment: @TommyBs It will go to the top everytime even if my input is below the page.

Comment: Then use scrollTo to scroll to a specific point. You just need to get the YPos of your input and add the 100px for your header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some idea.

```
var top = input.offset().top - 100;  // or input.position().top + 100;
$(document).scrollTop(top);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/AzRwm/

```
  <style>
#h{

background:black;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}
#s{
height:800px;
}
  </style>
  <header id='h'></header>
  <div id="s"></div>
  <input id="i" value='test' />
  <script>
      var i = document.getElementById('i');

     window.scrollTo(0,i.offsetTop + 100);
  </script>
```

Comment: I think there is some issue it always goes to the top. BTW thanks for your time and answer.